# Joomla 4 website's backend not working after renaming htaccess.txt to .htaccess

Tags: administrator, .htaccess-configuration, module-display, joomla-4.x, joomla-4

I got a issue after renaming htaccess.txt to .htaccess in the public_html folder of my Joomla 4 website (https://www.freepetsitters.com). I renamed it in order to get rid of "index.php" in the URLs.

#### Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Download Helix Ultimate 2 Beta 1 Quickstart Package (https://github.com/JoomShaper/helix-ultimate/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.1), upload it to the public_html folder of your website, unzip it and then follow the standard Joomla installation procedure.
2. Upgrade your website to Joomla 4 Beta 7.
3. Set "Use URL Rewriting" to "Yes" (In the Global Configuration tab of the Joomla administrator panel).
4. Rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess in the public_html folder of your website.
5. Delete the cookies and website data, then refresh the Joomla administrator panel's tab.

#### Expected result

The website's backend looking like it was (before renaming htaccess.txt to .htaccess) and working fine.

#### Actual result

The administrator panel looking weird and not working (There is no interactivity when clicking on any button).

#### System information

**LiteSpeed-based server**

PHP: 7.3 lsphp

Joomla: 4 Beta 7

Helix Ultimate: 2 Beta 1

#### Additional comments

Here is what I got in the logs file:

`WARNING ...    assets  No asset found for com_modules.module.92, falling back to com_modules`

I also don't think that the problem is related to the website's template (Helix Ultimate 2 Beta 1) since the issue only occurs for the backend and not the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the above problem is to **comment out the last section of the .htaccess file** (See https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/32892 and https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/33097 for more details).

I faced this issue because my LiteSpeed-based hosting server was already gzipping css and js files, so there was no need to gzip them again.

Comment: "the last section of the .htaccess file" - which section is that?

Comment: @MrWhite It is the last block of code. It is from this comment:  ## These directives are only enabled if the Apache mod_headers module is enabled.
## This section will check if a .gz file exists and if so will stream it
##     directly or fallback to gzip any asset on the fly
until the end of the file.